# What is the maximum length for a Zend_Currency's Symbol property?

Tags: php, zend-framework, currency

I need to save the currency symbol field from a Zend_Currency object to a DB. I need to set a maximum length for the DB field and I'm wondering what might be a safe value for this particular type of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the source](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Currency.php), the currency symbol can be one of four things:

1. Nothing
2. A single glyph ($, €, ¥, etc)
3. An abbreviation (USD, EUR, etc)
4. The full, unabbreviated name of the currency

Behind the scenes, fetching the symbol ends up asking Zend_Locale_Data for the `currencysymbol` value.

If you will be working with only a certain set of possible currencies, the longest legal value will be the longest of their names, and then only when you ask for that data.  If you could work with *any* currency, then the longest value would be the longest of *any* of the `currencysymbol` values in the locale files.